# How can I prevent animating elements inside an SVG from overflowing?

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG element that I'm using CSS3 to animate. I'm scaling (`transform: scale()`) elements inside the SVG but they are being shown outside the bounds of the SVG image as they animate.

I need to prevent an overflow on the `.shines` element. I know I can't set that the `<g>` element so I'm using `<svg>` inside the SVG to attempt get this to work.

Provided is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrf98/) for your testing pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the shape is round, try `border-radius: 100%`

JSFiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jrf98/2/)

```
.portal {
    height: 21px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 21px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: There's no need to emphasise the link like that. Do not roll back this edit. If you do the post will be locked.